# issue with publishing windows fom app c#

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I am trying to publish a windows form c# application. But I keep on getting the following error:

> Unable to copy file "App.config" to "bin\Debug\app.publish\Application
>   Files\WindowsFormsApp1_1_0_0_0\WindowsFormsApp1.exe.config.deploy".
>   The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully
>   qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the
>   directory name must be less than 248 characters.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe the error message is correct: the FULL path is longer than the limits?

Comment: The combination of the base path for your solution (i.e. `C:\MyCode\MyProjects\TestProjects\Project1`) and the publish path (shown in the error message above) is too long. You need to either rename some of your folders, the solution, or move it to a less deeply nested folder so that the entire concatenated path  is shorter than 260 characters.

Comment: thats a common windows folder restriction, In the publish settings change the folder to one that is not so deep in the directory tree or has shorter names.

Answer (score 2):

If the directory where the application is located is too long, you can move it to a shorter directory, and if it is close to C like "C:\source", the directory length will be shortened.